# Docker compose with multiple Dockfiles and images (Django+Angular)

Tags: django, docker

I'm building an app that uses Django and Angular that is split up into two different repositories and docker images.

My file structure is:

```
.
docker-compose.yml
djangoapp/
    Dockerfile
    manage.py
    ...
angularapp/
    Dockerfile
    ...
```

I've been unable to get it to work properly, all documentation I found on this seem to expect you to have the `docker-compose.yml` file together with the `DockerFile`.

I've tried multiple different variations but my current (not working) `docker-compose.yml` file looks like this:

```
version : '3'
services:
  web:
    build: ./djangoapp
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
```

This gives me error  `can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`.

If I go into the `djangoapp/` directory and create a `docker-compose.yml` file there according to the offical Docker docs, it works fine. So it's nothing wrong with the actual build, the issue is accessing it from outside like I'm trying to do.

**Update**: I also decided to add my Dockerfile located at `./djangoapp/Dockerfile`.

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
ADD requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /code/
```

Comment: How are you launching this? Are you sure that the compose file is building the Dockerfile as listed, and is not using an older version of the image that is perhaps missing `WORKDIR` or did not `ADD` contents to `/code/`?

Comment: @wmorrell I'm just doing `docker-compose up` in the same directory as the `docker-compose.yml` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was solved by rebuilding my Docker image with `docker-compose build web` command. Seems like at the stage when I was having the error, that build didn't include the files needed. So in the code that I show above in the question post, nothing is wrong, it just needed to be rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see it seems just to be a simple typo

```
version : '3'
services:
  web:
    build: ./djangoapp
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
```

That ./ is all your missing I think. I'm pretty sure without it the docker compose file doesn't go into the directory specified.

**Update**
Now that I saw your Dockerfile, I've noticed that you havent added the manage.py to your container. The same way you added your requirements.txt is what you need to do with the manage.py. When a Docker container is built, it only has what you give it plus any other file structure it has from the base Image.

You can either add it in the Dockerfile or you can have a shared volume between a local directory and a container directory. I think adding it in the Dockerfile would be easiest though.

Comment: Also, the default name for a docker file is `Dockerfile`, not `DockerFile`. I'm not sure if capitalization matters.

Comment: I tried both, makes no difference between `./djangoapp` and `djangoapp`. Both give the same response -- the manage.py file can't be found. Note that if I write some completely bogus like `./../asfaf/` it will throw an error, so I guess it can find djangoapp in both ways of typing the path.

Also, The capitalization of Dockerfile was a typo here on SO. I fixed it.

Lastly, I added my Dockerfile to the initial post.

Comment: @MarcusLind Did you end up figuring it out with my last update?

Comment: @LukeArthurs Yes I was able to figure it out. The solution was simply to rebuild the image with the docker-compose build command. I misunderstood at what times the image need to be rebuild.